# Unable to date range query results in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble querying the correct date range. My query does not seem to consider the Where clause for post_date > (date provided).

```
            SELECT `code`,
                `description`,
                SUM( IF( month = 3 && year = 2018, monthly_quantity_total, 0 ) ) AS monthlyqt,
                SUM( IF( month = 3 && year = 2018, monthly_price_total, 0 ) ) AS monthlypt,
                SUM( monthly_quantity_total ) AS yearlyqt,
                SUM( monthly_price_total ) AS yearlypt
            FROM (
                SELECT `invoices_items`.`code`,
                    `invoices_items`.`description`,
                    SUM( invoices_items.discounted_price * invoices_items.quantity_supplied ) AS monthly_price_total,
                    SUM( invoices_items.quantity_supplied ) AS monthly_quantity_total,
                    YEAR( invoices_items.datetime_created ) AS year,
                    MONTH( invoices_items.datetime_created ) AS month
                FROM `invoices_items`
                JOIN `invoices` ON `invoices`.`id` = `invoices_items`.`invoice_id`
                WHERE `invoices`.`is_finalised` = 1
                AND `invoices`.`post_date` > 2018-02-28                 
                AND `invoices_items`.`type` = 1                 
                GROUP BY `year`, `month`, `invoices_items`.`code`

                UNION ALL

                SELECT `credit_notes_items`.`code`,
                    `credit_notes_items`.`description`,
                    SUM( credit_notes_items.discounted_price * credit_notes_items.quantity_supplied * -1 ) AS monthly_price_total,
                    SUM( credit_notes_items.quantity_supplied ) AS monthly_quantity_total,
                    YEAR( credit_notes_items.datetime_created ) AS year,
                    MONTH( credit_notes_items.datetime_created ) AS month
                FROM `credit_notes_items`
                JOIN `credit_notes` ON `credit_notes`.`id` = `credit_notes_items`.`credit_note_id`
                WHERE `credit_notes`.`is_finalised` = 1
                AND `credit_notes`.`post_date` > 2018-02-28
                AND `credit_notes_items`.`type` = 1
                GROUP BY `year`, `month`, `credit_notes_items`.`code`
            ) AS sub
            GROUP BY code;
```

There are basically 4 tables being queried here. `invoices`, `invoices_items`, `credit_notes` and `credit_notes_items`.

table 1 - invoices

```
id    post_date    is_finalised
1     2018-01-01   1
2     2018-02-01   1
3     2018-03-01   1
```

table 2 - invoices_items

```
id    invoice_id    code    description    discounted_price    quantity_total    type
1     1             TEST-01 Test product   9.99                1                 1
2     1             TEST-01 Test product   9.99                2                 1
3     2             TEST-01 Test product   9.99                5                 1
4     3             TEST-01 Test product   9.99                5                 1
```

I have give some example rows above. From the table 1 and 2 above the desired result should be;

Desired Output

```
code    description    monthyqt    monthlypt    yearlyqt    yearlypt

TEST-01 Test product   5           49.95        5           49.95
```

However the output I am receiving is as below;

Received Output

```
code    description    monthyqt    monthlypt    yearlyqt    yearlypt

TEST-01 Test product   5           49.95        13          129.87
```

The query works as intended except for the date range I am trying to achieve by using the Where clause. You can see I am trying to filter out any row which are not matching `invoices`.`post_date` > 2018-02-28 (and also `credit_notes`.`post_date` > 2018-02-28).

I am not sure what I have done wrong here but any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. Basically the variable which was parsing the date value needed to be encapsulated in single quotes.

e.g.

```
invoices.post_date > '2018-02-28'
```

It's always something this simple which throws you off.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I have a hunch that your query could be a little more elegant

Comment: @Strawberry You are probably right. But because SQL queries are not my strongest point, I'm satisfied with whatever works well enough. Do you have any improvements to advise?